# PostgreSQL: How to create a prefixed sequence as a unique identifier?

Tags: sql, postgresql

One of my clients insists that I create a unique identifier that starts with a given prefix, then increments by one in a `postgres` table. For example, `PREFIX000001`.

I know postgres provides `SERIAL`, `BIGSERIAL` and `UUID` to uniquely identify rows in a table. But the client just does not listen. He wants it his way.

Here is the sample table (Excel representation) - something like `unique_id` column that auto generates on every `INSERT` command:
[image]

I really want to know whether this is technically possible in `postgres`.
How should I go about this?

Comment: Create a view when you have to show modified column values from a table.

Comment: @klin you mean the view on the front-end? Yes, it has been "discussed". No use. They want it in the database.

Comment: [create view ...](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html)

Comment: ohhh, I will definitely look into that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `SERIAL` or `BIGSERIAL` like you suggested but represent it with a string when reporting the data in the application (if the client would accept that):

```
 SELECT to_char(id, '"PREFIX0"FM0000000') AS unique_id, product_name, product_desc FROM table;
```

For example:

```
SELECT to_char(123, '"PREFIX0"FM0000000') AS unique_id;
  unique_id  
----------------
 PREFIX00000123
(1 row)

Time: 2.704 ms
```

---

Otherwise you would have to do this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_prefixed_seq;

CREATE TABLE my_table (
    unique_id TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'PREFIX'||to_char(nextval('my_prefixed_seq'::regclass), 'FM0000000'),
    product_name text,
    product_desc text
);

INSERT INTO my_table (product_name) VALUES ('Product 1');
INSERT INTO my_table (product_name) VALUES ('Product 2');
INSERT INTO my_table (product_name) VALUES ('Product 3');
```

->

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
   unique_id   | product_name | product_desc 
---------------+--------------+--------------
 PREFIX0000004 | Product 1    | {NULL}
 PREFIX0000005 | Product 2    | {NULL}
 PREFIX0000006 | Product 3    | {NULL}
(3 rows)

Time: 3.595 ms
```

I would advice you to try to make the client reconsider but it looks like you already tried that route

**To whomever reads this in the future, please don't do this to your database, this is not good practice as @Beki acknowledged in his question**

Comment: Yes, explaining stuff to your clients and advising them reasonably against whatever they want in Japan is often considered rude. @Gab thank you. Your answer solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

One method uses a sequence:

```
create sequence t_seq;

create table t (
    unique_id varchar(255) default ('PREFIX' || lpad(nextval('t_seq')::text, 6, '0'));
)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ff3a248a75282381c9182f72ca30aebd) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: stackoverflow only allows me to accept one answer. I am really grateful for both of your answers. If there is a way to accept multiple answers, I am all up for it. I actually used your answer. Let me know if there is any other way to thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As Gab says that's a pretty cumbersome thing to do. If you also want to keep a normal primary key for internal use in your app, here's a solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_prefix(INTEGER) RETURNS text AS
$$ select 'PREFIX'||to_char($1, 'FM0000000'); $$
LANGUAGE sql immutable;

CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    unique_id TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
        (add_prefix(id)) STORED,
    product_name text
);

INSERT INTO my_table (product_name) VALUES ('Product 1');
INSERT INTO my_table (product_name) VALUES ('Product 2');
INSERT INTO my_table (product_name) VALUES ('Product 3');

 select * from my_table;
 id |   unique_id   | product_name
----+---------------+--------------
  1 | PREFIX0000001 | Product 1
  2 | PREFIX0000002 | Product 2
  3 | PREFIX0000003 | Product 3
```

Sure, you get an extra index gobbling up RAM and disk space for nothing. But, when the client then inevitably asks you "I want to update the unique identifier" in a few months...

Or even worse, "why are there holes in the sequence can't you make it so there are no holes"...

...then you won't have to update ALL the relations in all the tables...

Comment: will definitely do. Thank you @bobflux

Comment: required viewing lol https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMXs9i201AQ

Comment: pretty clever @bobflux